# non-hypothetical 'would have to go'

Tags: modal-verbs, modality

> *Hitler himself related to me in 1930 – when we were speaking about his family relationships (in connection with a blackmail threat), ‘Even as a 10 or 12-year-old kid I always had to go late at night to this stinking, smoky dive. Without being spared any of the details, **I would have to go** to the table and shake him as he looked with a blank stare.*

Source: Martyn Housden: Hitler: A Study of a Revolutionary?, p. 169.

I assume that using would ("I would have to go") indicates the past tense. Can I replace "I would have to go" with "had to go" without a change of the meaning in the sentence? Is the reason for this usage clearly stylistic: the author does not want to be repetitive.

Answer (score 4):

*Would* is used here to express repeated or habitual action in the past:

> When I was a kid we would go to the drive-in during the summer.
>   Whenever we went to Nashville my father would visit his former professor, Donald Davidson.

In effect, *would* plays the same semantic role as *always* in the previous sentence.